# How do I set a hidden value based on ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select that uses the `ng-options` directive.

I would like to assign a second value to `$scope` based on the selected option.

```
  $scope.options = [
   {name: 'Apple', id: '1'},
   {name: 'Orange', id: '2'},
   {name: 'Banana', id: '3'},
   {name: 'Pear', id: '4'},
  ];
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fx7igqMjPsBQz1vtUlsM).

I am trying to declare the option.id based on the selected option.name so I can pass it in a `$http.post`.

Basically like a hidden field.  Is this a job for ng-init or something else?

Thanks!

Here's full plunker code.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="select">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="SelectController">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="select1">Select 1:</label>
    <select ng-model="newForm.select1"
            ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options | filter: newForm.select2 && {name: '!' + newForm.select2} | filter: newForm.select3 && {name: '!' + newForm.select3}" 
            class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row"><br></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="select2">Select 2:</label>
    <select ng-model="newForm.select2" 
            ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options | filter: newForm.select1 && {name: '!' + newForm.select1} | filter: newForm.select3 && {name: '!' + newForm.select3}" 
            class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
    <div class="row"><br></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="select2">Select 3:</label>
    <select ng-model="newForm.select3" 
            ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options | filter: newForm.select1 && {name: '!' + newForm.select1} | filter: newForm.select2 && {name: '!' + newForm.select2}" 
            class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <pre>
    <code>
      Select 1: Name:{{ newForm.select1 }} Id:{{ newForm.select1.id }}
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('select', []);

app.controller('SelectController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    {name: 'Apple', id: '1'},
    {name: 'Orange', id: '2'},
    {name: 'Banana', id: '3'},
    {name: 'Pear', id: '4'},
  ];

});
```

Comment: You could use `$index` of the selected option

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please edit your question

Comment: you can directly access it as `$scope.newForm.select1` and pass it in `http` service `post`

Comment: Can you add the code in your _plunker_ to the question post?

Comment: I can access $scope.newForm.select1 but I am also looking to access another attribute of the selected.  That would be option.id.  I want to include both option.name (used in the ng-option) and option.id.

Comment: Greg, thanks.  Any chance you have an example of using $index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) documentation:

> When an item in the  menu is selected, the array element or object property represented by the selected option will be bound to the model identified by the ngModel directive.

The `ng-model` for the first form is bound to `newForm.select1`. This means the selected option for the first form is available via:

```
$scope.newForm.select1
```

The values of the options in the `<select>` element must be the items in the `$scope.options` array:

```
<select ng-model="newForm.select1"
            ng-options="option as option.name for option in options | filter: newForm.select2 && {name: '!' + newForm.select2} | filter: newForm.select3 && {name: '!' + newForm.select3}" 
            class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Understood.  What I am trying to do is bind another attribute from the selected item to a different ng-model.

Comment: The attributes are available on the selected item. `$scope.newForm.select1.name` and `$scope.newForm.select1.id` both exist.

Comment: How do I access them?  If I edit my <pre> output to newForm.select1.name I get nothing.

Comment: Sorry gnerkus, I don't understand your edit.  name and id are in the array of options.  I am looking use name as the ng-option and then assign both name and the associated id of the selected to scope.  As name is the option, that works straight away, its connecting the id can't do.

Comment: Ah!  Sorry, now I see.  Remove the specificity of the first part of the ng-options="".